# JProfiler7.1.2 not working on windows

Tags: java, tomcat, jprofiler

I have installed Jprofiler 7.1.2 & tomcat 5.0.19 on WINDOWS XP. I have created one session with 127.0.0.1 as host & 8849 as port.

After clicking on OK button getting message as

> Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8849. Please make sure that the remote address is correct, the remote program is started properly, and the network route allows socket connections.

What else do I need to setup? What should I put in the start & stop commands for profiled JVM settings?

Answer (score 0):

That session will connect to a JVM where the profiling agent is already loaded.

To profile a JVM where the profiling agent has not been loaded, use

Session->Quick attach

in the JProfiler main menu.

Answer (score 0):

The following check list can be used to resolve the issue:

- Check if the JAVA_HOME is set to same version u r using for the application
- Validate for right values/parameters for %JAVA_OPTS%
- Set check box ON for VM Alive (under Settings -> Profile Settings)